# Transfer google contact photos to iCloud

Tags: icloud, messages, contacts, contacts.app

I recently switched from an Android to an iPhone. In the Messages app, it only displays the contact's initials, rather than their picture. Is there a way to  transfer these pictures from google into my iCloud?